# how to send .csv read data from JSP to HTML page, through url?

Tags: java, html, jsp, csv

I'm reading data from some .csv file & need to send that data to some HTML page through url only.
My JSP file only reads data from .csv & doesn't contain any HTML tag or form.
How shall I achieve it?

Comment: *"send that data to some HTML page through url only"*: What does that mean? Can you explain this, please?

Comment: I need to send the data read from .csv file to an HTML page - which processes data in URL.
If send the data to that HTML page through URL, it will process data as it is already coded to retrieve data from url & process it...

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean. Maybe you can edit your question, and show some example what you want to do or show what you have already tried and where you get stuck. *Send a file to an HTML page* makes no sense for me, I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You want to call something like http://yourserver/page.jsp?table=<url to csv file> ? And then what? Display this CSV? Display a table containing data from CSV?

Comment: @Alban: yes.. u got it.... actually I want to add the data (which is read from .csv file) to url like "www.somesite.com/some page.html?chkbx=on&txtbx=string&.....". My JSP page simply reads data from .csv file, adds it to an array... Now I wish to send that data to some HTML file which is designed to retrive data from URL & process it accordingly... Also, my JSP page doesn't have any HTML element like Form or submit button... I wish to achieve this simply by using scriptlets in JSP & not by using any form element...

Answer (score 0):

This is what we use to display simple reports.
It's currently lacking handling of quoted fields.

```
  <table >
    <tbody>
      <c:set var="newLine" value="<%= \"\n\" %>" />
      <c:forEach var="row" items="${fn:split(owdata:get('csv_file'), newLine)}" varStatus="rowStatus">
        <tr>
          <c:set var="rowSpaced" value="${fn:replace(fn:replace(row, ',,', ', ,'), ',,', ', ,')}" />
          <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${fn:contains(rowSpaced, ',')}">
              <c:forEach var="cell" items="${fn:split(rowSpaced, ',')}">
                <td>${cell}</td>
              </c:forEach>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
              <td colspan="10">${rowSpaced}</td>
            </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
          <td colspan="100"></td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```